# generate node-path from pairs of nodes

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate script that will build a path from the list of connections between different nodes (there can be more than one direct connection between 2 nodes). Also I am not looking to find shortest path, but all of them. Although each connection can be used only once in calculation.
It would be easier to explain if you imagine nodes in the computer network (e.g. `a1:1 = router a1, interface 1` etc).
for example, let say we have following 2 paths (second with 2 connections between each node):

```
a1:1 to b1:1| b1:2 to b2:1| b2:4 to a6:1
a1:5 to b5:1| b5:6 to a2:1
a1:7 to b5:2| b5:7 to a2:2
```

`a` nodes will always be the end points, but there can be any number of b nodes in the middle.

so the output I was looking to get would look something like:

```
a1-b1-b2-a6
a1-b5-a2 (in this case there are 2 connections between each of the nodes)
```

following is what I came up with so far but it's not working really good:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %paths;
my %connections =(
'a1:1' => 'b1:1',
'b1:2' => 'b2:1',
'b2:4' => 'a6:1',
'a1:5' => 'b5:1',
'a1:7' => 'b5:2', 
'b5:6' => 'a2:1',
'b5:7' => 'a2:2'
);

my %nodes;
for my $key ( sort keys %connections ){
    my $n1=(split(/:/,$key))[0];
    my $c1=(split(/:/,$key))[1];    
    my $n2=(split(/:/,$nodes{$key}))[0];
    my $c2=(split(/:/,$nodes{$key}))[1];
    $nodes{$n1}{$n2}{n_of_connections}[0]+=1;
    $nodes{$n2}{$n1}{n_of_connections}[0]+=1;
}
my $n=0;
foreach my $node ( sort keys %nodes ){
    $n++;
    foreach my $rnode (keys %{$nodes{$node}}) { # $rnode = "remote node"
        unless ($nodes{$node}{$rnode}{used}==1){
        $paths{$n}[0]=$node."-".$rnode;

    $nodes{$node}{$rnode}{used}[0]=1; #mark that it was used
    $nodes{$rnode}{$node}{used}[0]=1; #mark that it was used
    my $thisnode=$rnode;
    my $nextnode="";
    until ($nextnode =~ /a/){
        foreach my $x (keys %{$nodes{$thisnode}}) {
            unless ($nodes{$thisnode}{$x}{used}==1){
                $nextnode=$x;
                $paths{$n}[0].="-".$x;
                $nodes{$thisnode}{$x}{used}[0]=1; 
                $nodes{$x}{$thisnode}{used}[0]=1; 
                $thisnode=$nextnode;
            }   
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should generate all the possible paths from a1. It uses a recursive subroutine `path` which just walks all the possible connections.

I also used a different representation of the graph, the `%graph` hash. I created it from your `%connections` before calling `path`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub path {
    my ($start, $graph, $path) = @_;
    my @next = keys %{ $graph->{$start} };
    my $found;
    for my $n (@next) {
        for my $from_i (keys %{ $graph->{$start}{$n} }) {
            for my $to_i (keys %{ $graph->{$start}{$n}{$from_i} }) {
                delete $graph->{$start}{$n}{$from_i}{$to_i};
                path($n, $graph, [ @$path, "$start:$from_i $n:$to_i" ]);
                $found = 1;
                undef $graph->{$start}{$n}{$from_i}{$to_i};
            }
        }
    }
    print "@$path\n" unless $found;
}


my %connections = (
                   'a1:1' => 'b1:1',
                   'b1:2' => 'b2:1',
                   'b2:4' => 'a6:1',
                   'a1:5' => 'b5:1',
                   'a1:7' => 'b5:2',
                   'b5:6' => 'a2:1',
                   'b5:7' => 'a2:2',
                  );

my %graph;
while (my ($from, $to) = each %connections) {
    my ($from_r, $from_i) = split /:/, $from;
    my ($to_r, $to_i)     = split /:/, $to;
    undef $graph{$from_r}{$to_r}{$from_i}{$to_i};
}
path('a1', \%graph, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph). Specifically, [transitive closure](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph::TransitiveClosure).